# How can I change IntelliJ IDEA Maven remote repository URL?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, repository

[my IDEA setting (Maven Repositories)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yFAx.png)

My Maven repository URL is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
But this URL is unreachable. The correct URL of Central Maven Repository should be https://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2
With that incorrect URL, I cannot download any Dependency from Remote Repository.

How can I change the Remote Repository to the correct one?

Comment: The URL is reachable and the second as well. It might be that you can't reach that URL. I strongly recommend to check which Maven version you are using? And which IDEA IntellIJ version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 is the default maven repository. If you want to use other repositories, [add them to your pom file.](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories)

Comment: Thanks, add repository in pom.xml may help.